# Making a fight command, but health doesnt subsctract

Tags: python, discord.py, calculator

**Goal:** My goal is that you mention a user and it starts a battle, every 1 second a random amount between 5 and 20 health gets substracted from your current health. This happens until someone reaches 0 health.

**My problem:** In the upper code, the code sends a message every second, doesnt substract | In the bottom code the code doesnt send a message every second but it says *(edited)*. Also the substraction doesnt work

```
@client.command()
async def fight(ctx, user : discord.Member = None):
  turn1 = 100
  turn2 = 100
  beginner = ctx.author

  embedprogress=discord.Embed(title="⚔️Fighting!", color=0x7289da, description=f"{beginner.mention} ❤️ - {turn1}\n{user.mention} ❤️ - {turn2}")
  msg = await ctx.send(embed=embedprogress)

  while turn1 or turn2 > 0:
    turn1 - random.randint(5, 20)
    turn2 - random.randint(5, 20)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await msg.edit(embed=embedprogress)
  else:
    embedover=discord.Embed(title="⚔️Fight ended!", color=0x7289da, description=f"{beginner.mention} ❤️ - {turn1}\n{user.mention} ❤️ - {turn2}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embedover)
```

```
async def fight(ctx, user : discord.Member = None):
  turn1 = 100
  turn2 = 100
  beginner = ctx.author

  embedprogress=discord.Embed(title="⚔️Fighting!", color=0x7289da, description=f"{beginner.mention} ❤️ - {turn1}\n{user.mention} ❤️ - {turn2}")
  msg = await ctx.send(embed=embedprogress)

  while turn1 or turn2 > 0:
    turn1 -= random.randint(5, 20)
    turn2 -= random.randint(5, 20)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await msg.edit(embed=embedprogress)
  else:
    embedover=discord.Embed(title="⚔️Fight ended!", color=0x7289da, description=f"{beginner.mention} ❤️ - {turn1}\n{user.mention} ❤️ - {turn2}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embedover)
```

**The difference between the two codes is the equal sign in the `turn1 - random.randint(5, 20)` line.**

Comment: I would recommend just pasting one set of code, and then for the difference, you can just show that one line difference.

Comment: .. you mean the two lines are different

Comment: `turn1 or turn2 > 0` may be a mistake. Perhaps you want `turn1 > 0 or turn2 > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you defined the embed but when the health changed you didn't update it, and there were I few other errors that I fixed, I can tell you don't have much python experience I suggest you learn the language before you try to use it. here is the fixed code:

```
@client.command()
async def fight(ctx, user : discord.Member = None):
    turn1 = 100
    turn2 = 100
    beginner = ctx.author

    embedprogress=discord.Embed(title="⚔️Fighting!", color=0x7289da, description=f"{beginner.mention} ❤️ - {turn1}\n{user.mention} ❤️ - {turn2}")
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embedprogress)

    while True:
        turn1 -= random.randint(5, 20)
        turn2 -= random.randint(5, 20)
        embedprogress=discord.Embed(title="⚔️Fighting!", color=0x7289da, description=f"{beginner.mention} ❤️ - {turn1}\n{user.mention} ❤️ - {turn2}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await msg.edit(embed=embedprogress)
        if turn1 < 0 or turn2 < 0:
            break

    embedover=discord.Embed(title="⚔️Fight ended!", color=0x7289da, description=f"{beginner.mention} ❤️ - {turn1}\n{user.mention} ❤️ - {turn2}")
    await msg.edit(embed=embedover)
```

side note: if you need any more help add me on discord: LUNA#6969 I would be happy to help you.